# Redirect after iPhone\Android app install

Tags: android, iphone

Say I redirected a user to download my app from itunes via an "itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8&uo=6" link (or the equivalent Google Play link)

Is it possible to have him redirect to some url after the app is installed? (say my own schema url registered by my app) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect them away from the stores.

Edit: Imagine the security risk if it was possible :S

Answer (score 1):

Its different for both 1) android and 2) iphone
Lets say if you download your app from store (google play/itunes) then you can redirect user to any other link that is for sure, 
a) But you cannot redirect user to download another app (in case of iphone) as application are only distributed from iTunes and not any other sources
b) But this case is not true in case of Android, as application can be distributed from any source, google play is not only restricted place of distribution.

Comment: Yes its possible if you download the app from other source than google play store, you could put the app up on your own site with a redirection etc. but from the play store it is no go.

Comment: It is possible to redirect, even from google play store.. image admob appearing in applications, when you click they redirect you to another link

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, when you are on the play store (device or no device) you wont be redirected. The admob links don't direct you to store and then to another place afterword. Can you give an example of where it is used?